# Python, MySQL поиск в таблице

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, ubuntu, регистрация

```
import random
import mysql.connector
from re import L
import time
import os
import sys
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from getpass import getpass
from mysql.connector import connect, Error
g1 = 1
    def display_full_name():
    login1 = (name.get())
    password1 = (surname.get())
    try:
        with connect(
            host="",
            user=("admin"),
            password=(""),
            database="accs",
        ) as connection:
            print(connection)
            select_movies_query = f"""
            SELECT login, password
            FROM accounts
            WHERE login = ('{login1}')
            """
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(select_movies_query)
                for user in cursor.fetchall():
                    if user is str:
                        g1 == 0
                    else: 
                        g1=1
            if g1 == 1:
                insert_movies_query =f"""
                INSERT INTO accounts (login, password)
                VALUES
                ('{name.get()}', '{surname.get()}')"""
                with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                    cursor.execute(insert_movies_query)
                    connection.commit() 
            else:
                messagebox.showerror(title=None, message='Такой аккаунт 
уже зарегистрирован!',)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)





root = Tk()
root.title("Регистрация")

name = StringVar()
surname = StringVar()

name_label = Label(text="Введите логин:")
surname_label = Label(text="Введите пороль:")

name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
surname_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

name_entry = Entry(textvariable=name)
surname_entry = Entry(textvariable=surname)

name_entry.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
surname_entry.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)


message_button = Button(text="Регистрация", 
command=display_full_name)
message_button.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

root.mainloop()
```

Я веду поиск в таблице логина который игрок вводит при регистрации (where login = login1 в коде), мне нужно сделать так, чтобы если при поиске, выводило что на этот логин уже зарегистрирован аккаунт, открывался messagebox(я пытался через переменную g1, выдает ошибки) , помогите сделать это

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вы уверены что это весь код? что за скобка там в начале? Там чтото еще есть в оргинале? Лучше приводить весь код функции, чтобы вам могли помочь

Comment: Добрый вечер, сейчас скину всё

Comment: Поправил, буду ждать вашего ответа

Comment: Там где if user is str это я просто эксперементировал